# SSIS BCP Expressions

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bcp

I am trying to use bcp with SSIS and I have built my arguement string using an Expression. However, when I run the query I am getting an error:

```
    [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" 
"staging.dbo.t_gptransaction_char IN c:\data\gptransaction\gptransaction.csv -T -S Apollo -D Staging -f 
c:\data\gptransaction\t_gptransaction.fmt -e c:\data\log\gptransaction_error.log -t " at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
```

At first I had my working directory set to c:\data\gptransaction\ but I have tried removing it and I'm getting the same error. I am sure it is something trivial but I can't see it.

Comment: What happens if you copy the bcp command that is being executed, and try executing it from a command prompt?

Comment: @TabAlleman 's comment will show the real error, also check the error log file which you specified.  I suggest using a Dataflow instead since it is much more flexible than BCP, easier to configure and performs better.  Plus you get the built in logging from SSIS and can actually redirect rows with errors if you need that sort of thing.  BCP is fussy to configure and fussy to troubleshoot the layers of permissions issues.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the feedback. Tab great tip, I was using similar params in a python app but when I added them to SSIS I made a couple of changes and I was sure that the ps and python versions were ok so I didn't think to actually test the version in SSIS. As it turns out, there was two errors: 1) I was using a -D for the database instead of -d, 2) when specifying a database, you can't specify a 3-part value for the target table (first argument) if you are using a -d flag for the database. It is one or the other. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Mark, the files contain in excess of 3 rows of data, 100 columns of data. Using a DataFlow takes 4 hours to upload to the server. the same is true with a linkedServer objects, the data is way to big to transfer quickly. It actually puts a lock on the database. I opted for bcp, which at max 15-30 minutes. DataFlow is great but not at those volumes. Thanks again.